# Read from CSV file and save every value in a row in a variable

Tags: csv, powershell-4.0

I have this CSV file. Looks like this:

```
ID,Name,Surname,Energy, Sugar
1,Kim,Jansen,4343,45
2,Tim,Brown,5332,42
3,Paul,Redford,2345,36
```

I have a `Read-Host` statement in my script which asks for the ID. Once I have this - let's say it is 2 - I now want to import this CSV file and read the row where ID=2 and save the Name, Surname, Energy and Sugar in variables.

I have tried with `ForEach-Object` and so on, but it prints all the ID columns and saves only the last row.

How do I get the row values only if the `if` condition is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a `Where-Object` filter:

```
$id = Read-Host ...
$row = Import-Csv 'input.csv' | Where-Object { $_.Id -eq $id }
```

You can store the fields of the CSV in individual variables:

```
$name    = $row.Name
$surname = $row.Surname
$energy  = $row.Energy
$sugar   = $row.Sugar
```

but that's usually neither required nor recommended. Just use the properties of your object variable (`$row` in this example).

Comment: Thank you Ansgar. Very simple. I never thought of this.